Problem with AdomdConnection in Data Factory (PySpark)
I'm trying to connect SSAS (Microsoft Analysis Services) through Data Factory using PySpark with the code below but I'm having problems with Adomd mapping. Apparently there is no reference to the dll but I have no idea where it could be mapped as it is running on Azure (Data Factory - PySpark). Has anyone experienced this difficulty?
from pythonnet import load
load("coreclr")

import clr

from pyadomd import Pyadomd
.
.
.
with Pyadomd(connectionString) as conn:

NameError: name 'AdomdConnection' is not defined
Connect to Microsoft Analysis Services through Data Factory

The error message "NameError: name 'AdomdConnection' is not defined" suggests that the AdomdConnection object is not being recognized. This could be due to a missing reference to the necessary DLL. Since this code is running on Azure Data Factory with PySpark, you may need to ensure that the necessary DLL is included in your deployment package.
